# unix LS sort decending

Tags: bash

Currently, if I ls a folder, I get this:

```
problem10.java
problem11.java
problem12.java
problem13.java
problem13.txt
problem14.java
problem16.java
problem17.java
problem18.java
problem18.txt
problem19.java
problem1.java
problem20.java
problem21.java
problem22.java
problem22.txt
problem23.java
problem24.java
problem25.java
problem26.java
problem27.java
problem2.java
problem3.java
```

I want it to sort like

problem1.java
problem2.java
problem3.java
problem4.java
etc

I tried using ls folder | sort but it's still sorting alphabetically. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `ls -v`, which does exactly the numerically appropriate sort you describe. Read the man page; the 'v' stands for "Version", but it works with any kind of number, not ust version numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ls folder | sort -n
```

This will do numeric sort. Manual page of sort will help you a lot : )